# how to use enhanced for loop to print an array

Tags: java

this is a simple program that takes  calculates gross sales and determines how many people have earned salary in ranges ( 200 to 299, 300 to 399, so on..) 
i have stored the values in an array ( counter)
how do i use an enhanced for loop to print my array ( not counter controlled, only enhanced)

this is my program

```
public class Sales 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //declare
        double salesData[] = {750, 1200, 5000, 7575, 10000, 9250, 12500, 3560, 4800};
        double gross = 0;//[] = new double[9];
        int counter[]= new int[9];
        int i=0;


        //walk through sales data
        for(i=0; i<salesData.length;i++)
        {
            //calculate gross
            gross = 200 + salesData[i] * .09;

            //determine range and increment count array
            if((gross >200) && (gross  <= 299))
                counter[0] ++;

            else if((gross >300) && (gross  <= 399))
                counter[1] ++;

            else if((gross >400) && (gross  <= 499))
                counter[2] ++;

            else if((gross >500) && (gross  <= 599))
                counter[3] ++;

            else if((gross >600) && (gross  <= 699))
                counter[4] ++;

            else if((gross >700) && (gross  <= 799))
                counter[5] ++;

            else if((gross >800) && (gross  <= 899))
                counter[6] ++;

            else if((gross >900) && (gross  <= 999))
                counter[7] ++; 

            else if (gross >1000)
                counter[8]++;
            //print gross
            System.out.println(gross);

        }
```

Comment: Note that you could greatly simplify the actually complicated part of this loop by calculating the position to update, rather than using a series of `if`s: `int indexToUpdate = (int)((gross - 200) / 100);` Also, you currently skip over anything that lands on the hundred exactly. Is that intentional?

Comment: the sales array does not have anything that lands on 1000 so i skip over it. how do you print the counter(the array currently storing the ranges) ??

Answer (score 2):

```
double salesData[] = {750, 1200, 5000, 7575, 10000, 9250, 12500, 3560, 4800};

for(double data : salesData){
gross = 200 + data * .09;
//your logic
}
```

Comment: but i need to print the counter array with a for loop

Answer (score 1):

The same way you use it on any other collection:

```
for( double d : salesData) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced-for loop:

```
for(double b : salesData) System.out.println(b);
```

[Arrays.toString(double[] array)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(salesData));
```

Comment: ohh thank you! i used for(double b : salesData) System.out.println(b);

Answer (score 0):

```
    double[] salesData = {750, 1200, 5000, 7575, 10000, 9250, 12500, 3560, 4800};
    int[] counter = new int[9];

    //walk through sales data
    for (double salesDatum : salesData)
    {
        //calculate gross
        double gross = 200 + salesDatum * .09;
        int group = Math.min(8, (int)gross / 100 - 200);

        counter[group]++;
        //print gross
        System.out.println(gross);

    }
```